# Validate required for put_assoc

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my phoenix project, I have a posts and tags schema linked through a join table

```
schema "posts" do
    field :title, :string
    field :body, :string

    many_to_many :tags, App.Tag, join_through: App.PostsTags , on_replace: :delete
    timestamps()   
end?
```

How do i ensure that tags are present went using put_assoc?

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:title, :body])
    |> put_assoc(:tags, parse_tags(params), required: true)
    |> validate_required([:title, :body, :tags])
end
```

Both required: true on put_assoc and adding :tags to validate required do not work as I had imagined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`validate_length/3` can be used to check that the `tags` list is non empty:

Post Schema:

```
defmodule MyApp.Blog.Post do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias MyApp.Blog.Post


  schema "blog_posts" do
    field :body, :string
    field :title, :string
    many_to_many :tags, MyApp.Blog.Tag, join_through: "blog_posts_tags"

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(%Post{} = post, attrs) do
    post
    |> cast(attrs, [:title, :body])
    |> put_assoc(:tags, attrs[:tags], required: true)
    |> validate_required([:title, :body])
    |> validate_length(:tags, min: 1)
  end
end
```

Tag Schema:

```
defmodule MyApp.Blog.Tag do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias MyApp.Blog.Tag


  schema "blog_tags" do
    field :name, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(%Tag{} = tag, attrs) do
    tag
    |> cast(attrs, [:name])
    |> validate_required([:name])
  end
end
```

Validates successfully when `tags` is present:

```
iex(16)> Post.changeset(%Post{}, %{title: "Ecto Many-to-Many", body: "Lots of words", tags: [%{name: "tech"}]})
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil,
 changes: %{body: "Lots of words",
   tags: [#Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{name: "tech"}, errors: [],
     data: #MyApp.Blog.Tag<>, valid?: true>], title: "Ecto Many-to-Many"},
 errors: [], data: #MyApp.Blog.Post<>, valid?: true>
```

Produces an error when `tags` is empty:

```
iex(17)> Post.changeset(%Post{}, %{title: "Ecto Many-to-Many", body: "Lots of words", tags: []})
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil,
 changes: %{body: "Lots of words", tags: [], title: "Ecto Many-to-Many"},
 errors: [tags: {"should have at least %{count} item(s)",
   [count: 1, validation: :length, min: 1]}], data: #MyApp.Blog.Post<>,
 valid?: false>
```

Produces an error when `tags` is nil:

```
iex(18)> Post.changeset(%Post{}, %{title: "Ecto Many-to-Many", body: "Lots of words"})
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil,
 changes: %{body: "Lots of words", title: "Ecto Many-to-Many"},
 errors: [tags: {"is invalid", [type: {:array, :map}]}],
 data: #MyApp.Blog.Post<>, valid?: false>
```

Comment: Based on my testing, providing an empty list to put_assoc with required: true does not throw any errors. Rather, put_assoc throws an error when the passed parameter is nil, regardless of whether required: true is set.

Comment: Thanks @kuan, I've updated the answer to validate with `validate_length`, which should handle the empty list case.